# При использовании drag_and_drop_by_offset драйвер захватывает элемент, но переносит его не по заданным координатам, а в то место нахождения курсора

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

При использовании drag_and_drop_by_offset драйвер захватывает элемент, но переносит его не по заданным координатам, а в то место нахождения курсора, подскажите пожалуйста ошибку

## Функция

def chain(self, x_offset, y_offset):

```
    element = self.wait_to_be_clickable()

    if element:
        action = ActionChains(self._web_driver)
        action.drag_and_drop_by_offset(element, x_offset, y_offset).perform()
    else:
        msg = 'Element with locator {0} not found'
        raise AttributeError(msg.format(self._locator))
```

## Сам тест

```
    page = SettingsPage(self.driver)

    page.gear.click()
    page.productpage_settings.click()
    page.ex_links.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    page.seven_elem.chain(800, 207)

    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

x_offset, y_offset это координаты смещения мыши, т. е. вы перемещаете объект на 800 по X и на 207 по Y от первоначальной позиции. Если вам надо выставить его по определенным координатам, вам надо вычислить смещение.

Comment: Здравствуйте, дело в том что не важно какие координаты я задам, ведь он все равно понесет этот элемент к месту где находится мой настоящий курсор, даже если он за приделами браузера

Comment: Здравствуйте! По коду я ошибок не нашел. Но похоже, что координаты изменяются, на мышьи. В документации сказано, что перед выполнением .perform() данные сохраняются в стеке и затем последовательно выполняются. Может еще какая-та программа нарушает стек.